# Run an Ansible task only when the hostname contains a string

Tags: ansible

I have multiple tasks in a role as follows. I do not want to create another `yml` file to handle this task. I already have an include for the web servers, but a couple of our Perl servers require some web packages to be installed.

```
- name: Install Perl Modules
  command: <command>
  with_dict: perl_modules

- name: Install PHP Modules
  command: <command>
  with_dict: php_modules
  when: <Install php modules only if hostname contains the word "batch">
```

Host inventory file

```
[webs]
web01
web02
web03

[perl]
perl01
perl02
perl03
perl-batch01
perl-batch02
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Below should do the trick:

```
- name: Install PHP Modules
  command: <command>
  with_dict: php_modules
  when: "'batch' in inventory_hostname"
```

Note you'll have a couple of skipped hosts during playbook run.

`inventory_hostname` is one of Ansible's "magic" variables:

> Additionally, inventory_hostname is the name of the hostname as
> configured in Ansible’s inventory host file. This can be useful for
> when you don’t want to rely on the discovered hostname
> ansible_hostname or for other mysterious reasons. If you have a long
> FQDN, inventory_hostname_short also contains the part up to the first
> period, without the rest of the domain.

Source: [Ansible Docs - Magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables)

Comment: I can't edit this (says "too many pending edits") so I'll make a comment: This link 404's now. The updated doc link is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can even filter tasks for hosts of a specific group (not the whole inventory).

The following condition will execute your task - only if an inventory **group [perl]**, has a host name, which includes the **sub-string "batch"**:

```
 when: "groups['perl'] | select('search','batch') | list"
```

So if that group does not have a host with that sub-string, then the list is empty, which means false condition.