# ansible with_items stdout_lines filter

Tags: ansible

I have a list in a variable that I need to execute a shell command against.

```
   - name: Set Percentage value to "yes" to all disks for NFS SERVERS
    shell: |
      NUM=$(cat -n {{ cdm_path }} |\
            sed -n "/<disk>/,/<\/disk>/p" |\
            sed -n "/<alarm>/,/<\/alarm>/p" |\
            sed -n "/<fixed>/,/<\/fixed>/p" |\
            sed -n "/<{{ item }}>/,/<\/{{ item }}>/p" |\
            awk '/ percent = no/ {printf "%d", $1}')"s";
      if [ "${NUM}" != "s" ]; then
          sed -i "${NUM}/no/yes/g" {{ cdm_path }};
          echo "file_was_changed" ;
      fi
    with_items: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    register: percent_nfs
    when: ansible_hostname == "nfs01" or
          ansible_hostname == "nfs02"
    changed_when: '"file_was_changed" in percent_nfs.stdout'
```

result contains something like this:

```
#
#boot
#emc#dest#admin
#emc#dest#dbdata
#emc#dest#dbbackups
#emc#dest#lsgdev
#emc#dest#lsgdev_dev
#emc#dest#lsgdev_stage
#emc#dest#lsglegacy
```

I am running this code when ansible_hostname == nfs01 or nfs02

I need to keep 'result' the same for multiple devices, but I only want to execute the shell command with items that dont contain `*lsg*` in the name.

How can I further filter the with_items line to only use the filtered items?

Comment: Couldn't you just use add `and "lsg" not in item` to your `when:` condition?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a more elegant solution to your problem of excluding items, from `result.stdout_lines`, which don't include the sub-string `lsg`.

However, one possible solution would be to use a combination of the Ansible `difference` [set theory filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) and the Jinja2 `select` filter (similar to in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088489/7647013)) to filter your items, like below:

```
...
with_items: "{{ result.stdout_lines|difference(result.stdout_lines|select('search','lsg')|list) }}"
...
```